# React native Async storage save data via form

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have this data.js file in which I stock some data :

```
  export const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'first item',
    description: `my first item`,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Second item',
    description: `my second item`,
  },
];
```

And this is the add associated form with async storage in react native when the user enters some parameters in the form it supposed to add these to the data.js file but not working when I tested so many time and couldn't see my error :

```
import data from './model/data';
import {AsyncStorage}from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import React, {Component} from 'react';  
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text,  
  View,TouchableOpacity,  
} from 'react-native';  
  
export default class addPoint {  
  saveData(){  
    AsyncStorage.setItem(description,data.description);  
    AsyncStorage.setItem(title,data.title); 
  }  

  render() {  
    return (  
      <View style={styles.container}>  
        
        <Input placeholder=" Type your item title:" 
             onChangeText={(title) => this.setState({title})}
             value={title} /> 
        <Input placeholder=" Type your item description:" 
             onChangeText={(description) => this.setState({description})}
             value={description} />
          
        <TouchableOpacity onPress ={this.saveData}> 
        <Text>Click to save data</Text> 
        </TouchableOpacity>   
      </View>  
    );  
  }  
}  
  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
  container: {  
    flex: 1,  
    justifyContent: 'center',  
    alignItems: 'center',  
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',  
  },  
});
```

Please can you help me identify the problem ? And thank you in advance

Comment: Try changing `export default class addPoint` to `export default class addPoint extends Component` and bind `this` to `SaveData` in the `constructor`.
Your class constructor should look as follows.

`constructor(props){
super(props);
this.saveData = this. saveData.bind(this);
}`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I changed the export as you suggested and added the constructor right after the saveData function inside the addPoint class is this ok ?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Thanks so much I am testing now hope it works this time